# Check performance of ETL in SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, database-tuning, attunity

How can I check how long it lt took to extract data and load data in SSIS.
I am using Attunity connector now for extracting Data from Oracle and then using OLE DB destination to load it in SQL Server. Using Attunity is not making any difference in speed. It took approx 5 minutes to extract and load 5,600,000 rows from oracle to SQL Server when I use attunity connector which is same as OLE DB Source.

Comment: You can do as AsRa writes of you can create a Execute SQL task which writes down a select getdate() to a table before you start loading, and add an execute SQL task at the end of your load which also writes select getdate() to a table. Then you will have a log on how long it took.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Progress` tab, you can see the time taken for completion of data load.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the package duration is included in the GUI and you can also write the start/end times to a logging table within the package to capture the execution time.  If you're looking for more detail on specific components, enable logging, choose the **PipelineComponent** event, and look for this event on the tasks that you're looking to monitor.  The PrimeOutput step, which is when the data is sent downstream, will be of the most interest.